# Adding and linking resources with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, subnet, aws-cdk

I have been deploying with AWS CDK and deployed a VPC with 2AZ's 6 subnets (2 Public and 4 private) shared within the AZ's with CIDR of:

1. Private-Subnet     10.0.1.0/24
2. Private-Subnet     10.0.2.0/24
3. Private-Subnet     10.0.3.0/24
4. Private-Subnet     10.0.4.0/24

the CDK fails to deploy.

I'm discovering new things every day, CDK is not as straight forward and there are no tutorials. mostly when you append resources it just avoids them and deploys the usual.

```py
from aws_cdk import core,aws_ec2,aws_ecs,aws_ecs_patterns,aws_rds,aws_dynamodb

class TestCdkStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here

        subnets= []

        subnets.append(aws_ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "***-Web-Shared-Public-Subnet", subnet_type = aws_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC, cidr_mask = 20))
        subnets.append(aws_ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "***-Web-Shared-DBa-Private-Subnet", subnet_type = aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE, cidr_mask = 24))
        subnets.append(aws_ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "***-Web-Shared-ADa-Private-Subnet", subnet_type = aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE, cidr_mask = 24))

        vpc=aws_ec2.Vpc(self, '***-Web-Shared-VPC',
                        max_azs=2,
                        nat_gateways=2,
                        cidr='*.*.*.*/16',
                        enable_dns_support=True,
                        enable_dns_hostnames=True,
                        subnet_configuration=subnets,
        )
```

```
VPC
***-Web-Shared-VPC      10.0.0.0/16

Subnets
***-Web-Shared-DBa-Private-Subnet     10.0.1.0/24
***-Web-Shared-DBb-Private-Subnet     10.0.2.0/24
***-Web-Shared-ADa-Private-Subnet     10.0.3.0/24
***-Web-Shared-ADb-Private-Subnet     10.0.4.0/24

Route Tables
***-Web-Shared-DBa-Private-Route-Table
***-Web-Shared-ADa-Private-Route-Table

NaCl
***-Web-Shared-DBa-Private-NACL
***-Web-Shared-ADa-Private-NACL

Security Group
***-Web-Shared-DBa-Private-Security-Group
***-Web-Shared-ADa-Private-Security-Group
```

Requirements:

- Enable DNS Hostnames
- Make sure auto-assign public IPs is on public subnets
- On NACL a rule must be in incoming and outgoing which is 100 allowing all traffic.

I would like to specify IP's, Route tables, SG's and NACL. but I can't get through with that.

Instead, these are the IP's I get:

```
10.0.0.0/20,
10.0.16.0/20,
10.0.32.0/24,
10.0.33.0/24,
10.0.34.0/24,
10.0.35.0/24
```

Comment: I haven't played with CDK before, but in looking at your code... If you are wanting a specific set of CIDRs, why are you not specifying them in your code? The CDK is meeting your requested `cidr_mask`, so it seems to be working correctly. If you want something specific, then tell it so.

Comment: I think you need to tell CDK which CIDR you want for your VPC. CDK will then automatically divide it according to the masks provided.
If you want to segment your subnets manually, you can do so and provide `cidrBlock` for each subnet. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.PrivateSubnet.html

Comment: Me and my team yesterday spoke with the AWS Dev team in the UK. for some reason CDK is still in BETA stage so it is not out to the production so the problems we are facing are common problems.

I will give it a go Three months from now and see if it has been improved or not but for now, I'm trying to break a rock.